# C++ : create instance of derived class with a (copy of) an instance of a base class

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have seen many topics related to this, but none that can help me here.

I have class `B` which inherits from `A`, which I cannot modify as far as internal code (I cannot go and implement a copy-ctor there, nor do I know an exhaustive list of its attributes or anything).

I am given an instance of `A`. I want to create an instance of `B` which has all the data that `A` already has (and actually just override one method, and that's it). What is a way to achieve this ?

To be more specific : I want to subclass the `QTabBar` that comes with a `QTabWidget` and override the `wheelEvent` method (because I think it does not accept the event, which would prevents other parent widgets to see it - which was I want : the `QTabBar` accepts and consumes the `wheelEvent`, does what `QTabBar` already does with it, namely scroll through the tabs, and nothing else anywhere else).

But I use the Qt Designer, so the `QTabBar` is already created as part of the `QTabWidget` that I placed in the designer, and it has all the tabs and properties I have set via the Designer. I can use the `setTabBar` method of `QTabWidget` to replace it later in code, but and I want my custom tab bar to have all the data that the existing tab bar will have gotten from the auto-generated `QTabWidget` originally placed in the designer.

Qt also has forcefully disabled the copy-constructors of most or all of its classes, for some reason. So I am not sure how to easily construct a custom tab bar using an existing instance of the parent class `QTabBar`

Also, the `QTaskBar` is also not available in the Qt Designer, otherwise I would have right-clicked on it and said "Promote to<my subclass of `QTtabBar`>". If you click on the `QTaskBar` in the Designer, what you get is the QTabWidget that you placed and that has this `QTabBar`. And fair enough - but this avenue is then blocked for me.

Regardless of the specific Qt use case (though I am also highly interested in it), I am interested in an answer to the general question. But I fear that this is more or less outside the bounds of C++.

Comment: I would edit but the edit queue is full. Just to say that the `QTaskBar` is also not available in the Qt Designer, otherwise I would have right-clicked on it and said "Promote to<my subclass of QTtabBar>". If you click on the `QTaskBar` in the Designer, what you get is the `QTabWidget` that you placed and that has this `QTabBar`. And fair enough - but this avenue is then blocked for me.

Comment: Easiest solution would be probably move the Designer logic to your cpp, and then just use subclass of `QTabWidget` like you planned.

Comment: I have thought about it, but this might pull the rug from under a few people's feet. But it's doable, long-term. Especially if only pull the minimum amount necessary. But it's still quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly about Qt, but depending on class hierarchy you may look at the decorator pattern. It would work best if you have an abstract interface for `A` class.

```
class Ainterface {
public:
    Ainterface () {}
    Ainterface (const Ainterface &) = delete;
    Ainterface & operator=(const Ainterface &) = delete;
    Ainterface (Ainterface &&) = default;
    Ainterface & operator=(Ainterface &&) = default;
    virtual ~Ainterface () = default;

    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    // more methods
};

class A: public Ainterface {
    /* ... */
};
```

You create class B with `foo` overridden as follows:

```
class B: public Ainterface {
public:
    B(std::unique_ptr<Ainterface> a): a_(std::move(a)) {}
    void foo() override { /* your overridden code here */ }
    void bar() override { a_->bar(); }
    // more methods follow the pattern of `bar`
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Ainterface> a_;
};
```

---

Another approach if `A` does not have an abstract interface is to make `B`'s constructor accept `A&&`:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = default;
    A& operator=(A&&) = default;
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar(); 
    // more methods
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(A&& a): A(std::move(a)) {}
    void foo() override {}
};

...
A a;
B b(std::move(a));
```

Comment: This seems to still call the deleted copy constructor, somewhere inside `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Charles The simplest example compiles ok: https://godbolt.org/z/b7Whhq1cq

Comment: Ah you offered a new version, well this one I cannot even use, because A doesn't have such an interface AFAIK, and I cannot modify it.

Comment: @Charles, yes, the first version would not compile, but not due to `unique_ptr`, but because if `B` inherits from `A`, then `B`'s constructor has to init `A`.  However, I've not thought how to overcome this, see the new edit.

Comment: Sorry, still no success, the version without the interface is still a call to a deleted constructor of A ... I think in my case, in `A`'s definition, instead of `A(A&&) = default;` I have `A(A&&) = delete;`

Comment: @Charles, well, you asked for a generic solution :) If in Qt you can not copy nor move the class, then I don't think there is any method short of byte-by-byte copy, and even that would be very fragile.

Comment: Yes, more reading has made me change my mind about how to approach my problem in Qt. Basically, it's a bad idea to try and copy most Qt objects, because of good reasons down the line.